# PayPal subscriptions: executed billing agreement ensures payment?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

Say a billing agreement has been executed. Then I receive a "BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CREATED" notification. Can I be sure that the payment for the first billing period will eventually reach the merchant account?  I'm expecting the "PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED" webhook notification.